# fetch data using class inside iframe and div using html, java script asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have an iframe and inside this there is a class called service-row and inside this div there is another class named service-cell

I want to get the data from that class how to do that. And there are 40 items with same name class how to get that data.

example

```
HTML page

<iframe id="iframe1">
     <div class="servicesTab">
          <div class="service-row">
               <div class="service-cell">
                   Obstetrics(this data)
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: All 40 items are present in the `iframe1`?

Comment: yes all the 40 items are present in ifram1 also the same class service cell

Comment: What kind of data do you want to get ? Code shared by you isn't sufficient to give proper answer.  I could only suggest  you to iterate using  JQuery `$.each()` taking `service-row` or `service-cell` as selector and read child elements. this way you can get child data for 40 items.

Comment: heres the link [link](https://www.practo.com/delhi/clinic/apollo-cradle-royale-nehru-place?subscription_id=500242&specialization=Gynecologist/Obstetrician&show_all=true) m sharing to u and i want all the services data from the different pages from this website using java scrip or asp

Comment: i also want to know the code to acess the data from class inside iframe. help me out

Comment: @Niteshkumar: Sorry buddy but this ain't a code writing service. SO will help only if are stuck somewhere in your code for that you need to try yourself first. The link you have shown I guess you want to perform some sort of website scraping.

Answer (score 0):

If you need data of specific cell then you can use the following code:

```
$("#iframe1 .service-cell:eq(0)").text()
```

else you can access all the cells using below code and then, iterate using for loop :

```
$("#iframe1 .service-cell")
```

Comment: aslo how can i store all this data to a particular div, and tell me how to implement the loop

Comment: <p class="doc-qualifications">MD - Obstetrics &amp; Gynaecology
                                    </p>
                                        <p class="doc-exp-years">
                    38 years experience </p>
                        <p class="doc-specialties"><span itemprop='medicalSpecialty' >                            Gynecologist/Obstetrician</span> </p>